# Is This Song in Italian?

Tags: regional

Is this a song in the Italian Language?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxueI0zB4lQ&t=11m37s

Below I have provided a transcript of the lyrics of the song as I hear it. Is there some way to turn this into Italian?

*provari fum qi yo si amna*

*esule dal purfecto*

*etucai etucare*

*que dol faraca dolei*

*apando itamai itamai*

*apando itamai itamai*

*enima mia*

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed Italian, but the musical ornamentation <strike>and the apparently non-Italian pronunciation of the singer</strike> makes it actually difficult to parse, even for an Italian.

The text says:

> Procuri pur ch'io sia
>   Esule dal tuo affetto e dal tuo core,
>   Che non farà ch'amore
>   Abbandoni già mai l'anima mia.

More or less (I don't know the context), it say that even if she is exiled from someone's affection and heart, nonetheless her love won't leave her soul.

It's a verse from the cantata “Usurpator tiranno della tua libertà”, on a text by an anonymous author and with music by Giovanni Felice Sances (1600?-1679). [Here](http://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=70273) you can find the whole text (not always perfectly transcribed).

Comment: Having answered, let me remark that your attempt at transcribing reads like a cross between an interlingual [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) and Chaplin's [song in _Modern Times_](https://youtu.be/0daS_SDCT_U). :)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the prompt reply, and even identifying the song itself! As for my transcription, I'm happy I got at least some of the words right given that I have zero knowledge of Italian.

Comment: The singer is Monica Piccinini who is a native Italian speaker: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ31755SyEI&t=2m16s
Maybe she sings in a regional dialect of Italian? I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, of course I didn't mean to criticise your transcription! Thanks for the info about the singer.